# Using ordinal numbers

Tags: numbers

I'm pretty familiar with constructing ordinal numbers (첫번째, 두번째, 세번째, etc.) but just double checking how I'd use them in a sentence.

예)

The second time I went to Korea, I stayed in Busan.

Would the first part simply be phrased as "한국에 두번째로 갔을때..."?

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible. Or 두번째 한국 방문시기에, 부산에 있었다.

Comment: It's okay. It's natural to say "한국에 두 번째로 갔을 때".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is natural.

한국에 두 번째로 갔을 때, or 두 번째로 한국에 갔을 때

When you use ordinal numbers, you should put space between number(첫, 두, ...)  and '번째' like 첫 번째, 두 번째.